# QgsGeometry.fromWkt() seems weirdly slow compared to OSGeo/Shapely

Tags: pyqgis, shapely, performance, osgeo

```py
wkt = 'LineString (64763.65372879413189366 5532941.864832429215312, 64811.82167246036988217 5533046.30194362625479698, 64827.02791490274103126 5533082.7359510725364089, 64833.97425112823839299 5533108.97413910925388336, 64836.81289814347110223 5533128.83601441606879234, 64837.85930135692615295 5533148.54203082248568535, 64829.66618683453270933 5533189.90297761932015419, 64763.48674955794558628 5533335.92280863784253597, 64698.15334041136520682 5533484.11210028734058142, 64695.89355474826152204 5533536.777954644523561, 64693.6449010342330439 5533610.49195305537432432, 64662.65355479739082512 5533709.0744445351883769, 64540.65852483704657061 5533940.2945637172088027, 64502.48707144402578706 5533982.01771332323551178, 64457.91474733040377032 5534013.94946065079420805, 64383.26389680442662211 5534053.9890363747254014, 64356.85891358827211661 5534073.3228508997708559, 64264.74203495683468645 5534163.33477118797600269, 64119.75953014766855631 5534269.2359554935246706, 64019.27142580858344445 5534343.1897652680054307, 63984.40616129212867236 5534381.67155505437403917, 63957.2219416404113872 5534426.87383262906223536, 63919.22859943267394556 5534546.1721246549859643, 63904.34518351361475652 5534577.99670103285461664, 63884.6638975413661683 5534601.41691596619784832, 63856.86742069028696278 5534625.47649374883621931, 63775.03646300815307768 5534670.00948977563530207, 63737.00972495316091226 5534695.55057103559374809, 63710.1594637738307938 5534731.74168855138123035, 63683.54297352516005049 5534792.22686298564076424, 63669.32747455085336696 5534824.42653318028897047, 63659.86531783342070412 5534845.85146155022084713, 63624.1206293396971887 5534887.32926813792437315, 63587.40746127608872484 5534917.92316982615739107, 63466.4588345291922451 5535015.78692159615457058, 63359.90381794186396291 5535114.74327577371150255, 63286.64446105081151472 5535188.31410792749375105, 63253.88313491034932667 5535212.78067360818386078, 63208.88779673171666218 5535236.56117806304246187, 63167.44355030937731499 5535248.0226236991584301, 63053.6861626677273307 5535257.86232526693493128, 62990.75725452229380608 5535268.63766833487898111, 62934.69675895879481686 5535287.13199165742844343, 62857.51895599182171281 5535322.24947791360318661, 62621.15428119046555366 5535446.6743788905441761, 62508.22065778069372755 5535481.24668284598737955, 62397.3353130015093484 5535485.00488888286054134, 62320.81429503022081917 5535473.44957983214408159, 62282.35341096115007531 5535458.1984656248241663, 62210.34083236697188113 5535436.72531438432633877, 62157.93161610149400076 5535427.54037262685596943, 62121.95315667710383423 5535429.84830279089510441, 62084.14905760371038923 5535446.6743788905441761, 61994.26970073721167864 5535504.29495839029550552, 61786.380551680791541 5535649.33825275953859091, 61714.59061206820479129 5535884.1008892459794879, 61622.79655996007204521 5536260.36687454953789711, 61607.0782478600522154 5536324.77671071048825979, 61588.63260823562450241 5536421.57946899347007275, 61581.85325124630617211 5536470.92478635627776384)'
wkb = bytes(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt).asWkb())

from qgis.core import QgsGeometry
from osgeo import ogr
```

```py
# WKB
from shapely.wkb import loads as loads_wkb
get_ipython().run_line_magic('timeit',  'line = loads_wkb(wkb)')
get_ipython().run_line_magic('timeit', 'line = QgsGeometry(); line.fromWkb(wkb)')
get_ipython().run_line_magic('timeit', 'line = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(wkb)')
```

> shapely: 11.5 µs ± 88.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
>
> pyqgis: 1.56 µs ± 97.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000
> loops each)
>
> osgeo: 858 ns ± 18.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

```py
# WKT
from shapely.wkt import loads as loads_wkt
get_ipython().run_line_magic('timeit',  'line = loads_wkt(wkt)')
get_ipython().run_line_magic('timeit', 'line = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt)')
get_ipython().run_line_magic('timeit', 'line = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)')
```

> shapely: 54.4 µs ± 840 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
>
> **pyqgis: 390 µs ± 795 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)**
>
> osgeo: 39.7 µs ± 1.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

Running this simple benchmark shows that creating a geometry from a WKT string is 10 times slower using `PyQgis` than `OSGeo`. I was wondering if there was a particular reason why that was. if it is not well optimized ?

I would have expected to get about the same order of magnitude for both `PyQgis` and `OSGeo` since they are both Python wrappers of C++ libraries. Which is the case for creating a geometry from a WKB byte array.

versions:

- QGIS: 3.22.11
- OSGeo (GDAL/OGR): 3.5.1
- Shapely: 1.8.0

Comment: I would imagine the devs felt that no one who was in a hurry would mess around with a text based geometry for more than an item or two so didn't bother worrying about it.

Comment: That does kind of makes sense.

Comment: If you think it would be useful that this gets optimized, I think posting a [QGIS github issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues) will probably be the way to go.